# Creating a sub subdomain in a subdomain

Tags: apache2

I have a virtual server with IP and a sub domain. Let's say the main one is `www.company.example` and my server is under `myserver.company.example`.

The server has Ubuntu Server 18.04 OS. I have multiple projects and I want to divide them in different sub subdomain in this case.

I have installed Apache Server App and under the `/var/www/html/` I have `/var/www/html/project1` and `/var/www/html/project2`. How can I make something like: `project1.myserver.company.example`?

Comment: Google `apache virtualhost`

Answer (score 1):

That's what virtual hosts (apache, nginx) or bindings (iis) are made for. Make sure your DNS is pointing to "your" IP address, especially for the sub-subdomains. Technically this is not a problem, neither the webserver nor DNS.